# Extract data from Dom using jquery

Tags: html, jquery, dom

I have the following Dom from which I need to extract some data.More precisely I need to extract the time (1:25 am & 5.25 am) using jquery. Is it even possible to do it on such a complicated dom??

```
<div style="background-size: cover;"><div style="background-size: cover;"><div class="hc-inline-block hc-valign-middle hc-mr1" style="background-size: cover;">1:25am</div><div class="hc-inline-block hc-valign-middle hc-mr1" style="background-size: cover;">-</div><div class="hc-inline-block hc-valign-middle" style="background-size: cover;">4:00am</div></div></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
console.log($(".hc-inline-block").first().text())
console.log($(".hc-inline-block").last().text())
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="background-size: cover;">
  <div style="background-size: cover;">
    <div class="hc-inline-block hc-valign-middle hc-mr1" style="background-size: cover;">1:25am</div>
    <div class="hc-inline-block hc-valign-middle hc-mr1" style="background-size: cover;">-</div>
    <div class="hc-inline-block hc-valign-middle" style="background-size: cover;">4:00am</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you @Nikhil Parmal. Really appreciate your help. 

Do you mind telling me what other paramteters can i use other than .first() and .last() ??

Just need to catch some more values inside the dom.

Comment: you can apply class or id to that particular div which contains time. and by that id or class you can directly get that time.

Comment: Is there a way i can get a third element of the dom (which is not the last one) ??

Comment: I am trying something like this but does not work... `console.log($(".hc-inline-block")[2].text());`  ... What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Try this `$(".hc-inline-block:nth-child(3)").text()
`

Answer (score -1):

The DOM in the question is malformed.  Opening and closing tags do not match up.

Notwithstanding this, if you give your div an Id then you can use:

**Html**

```
<div id="timeDiv"> 
  1:25am
</div>
```

**Script**

```
var content = $("#timeDiv").html();
```

This will return the html values (e.g. "1:25am") from the div.

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your comment. That is a word press dom and I can not change it... (the dom is wellformed but i had not copy/paste all the tags)